# Why is the work done on the system not equal in frame of gas and surroundings?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, isotherm

Consider an isothermal irreversible process for an ideal gas in a cylindrical container closed with a piston (system). Initial and final states are $(P_1,V_1,T)$ and $(P_2,V_2,T)$ respectively. Initially the pressure of surroundings was $P_1$ and which is increased to $P_2$,

Work done by surroundings on the system is $W_1=P_2(V_1-V_2)$ which is in the frame of surroundings. If we see in the frame of gas, work done on system is $W_2=\int -P_{\text{gas}} dv$

Since, process is isothermal and $P_{\text{gas}}V=nRT$ $$W_2=nRT\ln{\frac{V_1}{V_2}}$$

I am unable to figure it out that why is $W_1≠W_2$ because according to the first law it should be same (change in internal energy and heat exchange is same in both the frames) . Can please someone help me out?

Comment: You used the ideal gas law to get Pgas for the irreversible non-equilibrium process?  Do you think that is allowed?

Comment: @ChetMiller why not?

Comment: Are you familiar with the dissipative property of fluids (liquids and gases) known as viscosity?  Have you ever heard the term "viscous Newtonian fluid?"

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes.

Comment: If you are familiar with both of these, then are you familiar with the 3D mathematical form of the equations for the Cartesian components of stress tensor in terms of the thermodynamic pressure, the fluid viscosity, and the velocity gradients in the fluid?

Comment: @ChetMiller No (I am a high school student), but If you give me hint about what is going in the background of the process inside the gas, that would be helpful too.

Comment: @ChetMiller, Yes I am familiar with the stress tensor but I am unable to guess the reason using this. And I am desperate to know. Can you please write answers?

Comment: It might be helpful to think of a gas in a cylinder, not just as a compressible spring (in terms of pressure-volume behavior), but as a combination of a spring in parallel with a viscous damper (dashpot).  The spring would account for the equilibrium behavior at low rates of volume change, but the damper would come into a play at significant rates of volume change.  So the behavior of the gas would not just depend on volume,  but also on rate of change of volume.

Comment: @ChetMiller Do you mean the gas will not be ideal anymore? But how is it possible initially and finally the gas is ideal but not during the process? And are we able to deduce pressure inside to container as a function of volume?

Comment: The gas will still satisfy the ideal gas law under equilibrium thermodynamic conditions.  But, just because we call it an ideal gas at equilibrium does not mean that it will satisfy the ideal gas law under non-equilibrium conditions.  A gas or liquid behaves as a Newtonian fluid under all conditions (both equilibrium and non-equilibrium), but  a Newtonian fluid reduces to the ideal gas law (or other real gas equation of state) at thermodynamic equilibrium

Comment: @ChetMiller where could I get text regarding this in much more detail? Does Atkins have it? My teacher never taught that ideal gas equation is valid only under equilibrium conditions.

Comment: Maybe your teacher isn't aware of this.  See Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, particularly chapter 1.

Comment: @ChetMiller I think the book you told. I think it isn’t for high school student? Is it? I read the book from library I wasn’t even able to understand the first page. Can you suggest something introductory?

Comment: You were looking at page 1 of Chapter 1, right; not Chapter 0.  Well, this is kind of a complicat subject, and is built on gradually.  The math requires calculus and partial derivatives.  I don't think they cover partial derivates yet in HS.  I don't know what else to suggest.  Part of Chapter 1 (section 1.2) gives the physical motivation for the Newtonian fluid derivation.

Comment: @ChetMiller okay I will try to. I meant chapter 1 to chapter 0 and thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for @Chesx

For non-polymeric fluids (liquids and gases), Newton's law of viscosity very accurately describes the state of stress within a fluid as a function of the local fluid deformation and local rate of deformation.  It also reduces to the ideal gas law (or other thermodynamics equilibrium equation of state) in the limit of low rates of deformation (i.e., low velocity gradients).

In Cartesian coordinates, the components of the compressive stress tensor are related to the thermodynamic pressure p(v,T) and the fluid velocity gradients by:

$$\sigma_{xx}=p(v,T)-\frac{2}{3}\mu\left[2\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}\right]$$
$$\sigma_{yy}=p(v,T)-\frac{2}{3}\mu\left[-\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+2\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}\right]$$
$$\sigma_{zz}=p(v,T)-\frac{2}{3}\mu\left[-\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+2\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}\right]$$
$$\sigma_{xy}=\mu\left[\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\right]$$
$$\sigma_{xz}=\mu\left[\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z}\right]$$
$$\sigma_{yz}=\mu\left[\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial z}\right]$$where the u's are the components of gas velocity, v is specific volume, and $\mu$ is the gas viscosity.

In the limit of low gas velocities, these equations reduce to the isotropic thermodynamic equilibrium state values of the stress components:$$\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{yy}=\sigma_{zz}=p(v,T)$$and$$\sigma_{xy}=\sigma_{xz}=\sigma_{yz}=0$$
For a fluid satisfies the ideal gas thermodynamic equation of state $$p=\frac{RT}{v}$$

We also see from all this that the isotropic thermodynamic pressure p does not capture the state of stress in a gas that is deforming at finite rate. In fact, what we call the pressure is not the force per unit area on an internal surface  of arbitrary orientation, but rather it is merely the isotropic part of the overall stress tensor.